# Binding dropdown in Angular JS having wrong value in option

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new in Angular js and having problem while populating Drop down.

I have created user data array in foreach loop of data which i get from server.

```
$scope.Users.push(
                    {
                        userid:     item.Id,
                        loginname:  item.LoginName,
                        titlename:  item.Title,
                        emailid:    item.Email,
                        siteadmin:  item.IsSiteAdmin,
                        name:       item.Title,
                        value:      item.Id
                    }
                );
```

Now i am bind this data in drop down as **name** and **value**. But wrong value are populate in drop down.

```
<select ng-options="user.value as user.name for user in Users" 
        ng-model="taskusers" class="form-control">
</select>
```

It render as

```
<select ng-options="user.value as user.name for user in Users" ng-      model="taskusers" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="0">A</option>
  <option value="1">B</option>
  <option value="2">C</option>
  <option value="3">D</option>
  <option value="4">E</option>
  <option value="5">F</option>
  <option value="6">G</option>
  <option value="7">H</option>
  <option value="8">I</option>
</select>
```

It not render value of user in value field.

Excepted output is

```
<select ng-options="user.value as user.name for user in Users" ng-model="taskusers" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Select User</option>
  <option value="Value of A">A</option>
  <option value="Value of B">B</option>
  <option value="Value of C">C</option>
  <option value="Value of D">D</option>
  <option value="Value of E">E</option>
  <option value="Value of F">F</option>
  <option value="Value of G">G</option>
  <option value="Value of H">H</option>
  <option value="Value of I">I</option>
</select>
```

This is JSON DATA i am receiving.

[image: JSON DATA]

Please Help..!!

Comment: Post json data example! 0,1,2,3 are ids? in value property you are setting `item.id`, code looks correct, maybe a data problem

Comment: Item.Id having correct value which hold value of user-id..!! May be problem in binding values.

Comment: This is one of those weird angular things, you really should just be receiving the object and then doing what you wish with it, rather than mapping out the values, as this indirectly binds your controller logic with the UI (your controller now knows/needs to have a select list to auto update).

Comment: @KaushalKhamar so where is stored the '`Value of A`' value?

Comment: There is numeric value in item.value field. I am posting json data in question.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `$scope.taskusers` you will the selected user

or in your html you can do something like `<p>{{taskusers.loginname}}</p>`